# WCF Service called from winforms when to close?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

I have a WCF business Layer I am accessing from my winforms application with a per call instance context.

When should I be closing the the connection?  Should I create a new client on each form?

Right now I'm using A Channel Factory with my interface created on every form, but I am not closing them. It would seem to me if the service is percall I wouldn't need to as the service objects are creating and destroying themselves freeing up the servers resources. Not really into the service reference route, but if that is the better way I'll adopt it.

From what I read on MSDN the service instance is created and destroyed with each call, but they are not real clear on when to create and destroy the client. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183865.aspx

Any help\thoughts is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My hunt is allways try to make the most quick, small, all-managed call as possible! Keep the PerCall listener, but try to build some abstraction between your DB and the calls to your WCF.

Comment: I concur with @ElekGuidolin - the pattern I use is create the channel, make the call, close (or abort if needed) the channel.   Very rarely do I persist a client across multiple calls.   Most of the WCF services I use are hosted in IIS, and not closing channels can result in a very ambiguous error being returned when IIS runs out of resources.

Comment: That was my gut feeling, to treat it as one would do an ADO.net connection object. Thanks for the suggestions. I think that's the way to go.